# Difference between autocompleteList and autocompleteMethod in rich:autocomplete?

Tags: java, jsf-2, autocomplete, richfaces

I am read the doc of `autoComplete` but i cant get it.

- autocompleteList - A collection of suggestions that will be presented to the user.
- autocompleteMethod - A method which returns a list of suggestions according to a supplied prefix.

When we want to use autocompleteList and autocompleteMethod?
Both attribute give the list.

Welcome to any answer.

Answer (score 0):

- autoCompleteList - retrieves the whole list
- autoCompleteMethod - calls a method and passes the value to it so you can filter the list on server side

But it depends on what mode you use, if you use `client` or `lazyClient` mode the list is loaded just once and the rest happens on the client side (so there's no difference between *Method and *List); with `cachedAjax` the list is retrieved only when the cache for the current input is empty, with `ajax` the list is retrieved every time. If you're not going to do any server-side filtering you won't need autoCompleteMethod.